# cakephp call a function of another model error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a site develop in cakephp 2.x
I want into my controller call a function of another controller like this:

```
class ProductsController extends AppController {
    public $name = 'Products';
    public $scaffold;
    public $uses = array('Product','Unit');

        public function testFunction(){
             $this->loadModel('Unit');
             $this->Unit->test();
        }
}
```

The function test into UintController.php is this:

```
public function test(){
                 echo("test");
            }
```

My model name are Product and Unit.
When I call the function test give me this error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'prova' at line 1
```

In the function now is empty but give me this error.
I have tried with:

```
public $uses = array('Unit');
```

and to cancel the line with $uses.

How can I solve it?

Comment: this code does not reflect the error message. `$this->Unit->test()` refers to a function in the `Unit` model, not the controller. Post the `test()` function code.

Comment: Why downvote??? I have edit the question but in that I have already write that into  the function test there in nothing. Te problem isn't in the function but when I call it.

Comment: It's a MySQL error... please post the MySQL that's being generated.

Comment: @Dave there isn't MYSQL if you seen, cakephp if doesn't find the action/function use that like a command in SQL but doesn't exist this command in SQL this produce my error

Comment: Then why did you post a MySQL error?:  "1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax..."

Comment: Well because cakephp return me that error, because it doesn0t find a method with taht name and try to execute an sql command with that name and return error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To call a function from another controller you can use the [requestAction](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3arequestAction):

### Definition

> "This function calls a controller’s action from any location and returns data from the action. The $url passed is a CakePHP-relative URL (/controllername/actionname/params). To pass extra data to the receiving controller action add to the $options array".

### Usage

This is what your code would looks like:

```
class ProductsController extends AppController
{
    public $name = 'Products';
    public $scaffold;
    public $uses = array('Product','Unit');

    public function testFunction() {
        // Calls the action from another controller            
        echo $this->requestAction('/unit/test');             
    }
}
```

And then in the `UnitController`:

```
class UnitController extends AppController
{
    public function test() 
    {
        return 'Hello, I came from another controller.';
    }
}
```

### Warning

As said in the CakePHP Cookbook:

> "If used without caching requestAction can lead to poor performance. It is rarely appropriate to use in a controller or model".

### Best solution for you

But, the best solution for you, would be to create a function inside a model and then call from your controller, like this:

```
class ProductsController extends AppController {
    public $name = 'Products';
    public $scaffold;
    public $uses = array('Product','Unit');

    public function testFunction() {
         echo $this->Unit->test();
    }
}
```

And in the `Unit` model:

```
class Unit extends AppModel
{
    public function test(){
        return 'Hello, I came from a model!';
    }    
}
```